# how to get sub 2d tensor with specific value condition in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to copy a 2-d torch tensor to a destination tensor containing only values until the first occurrence of 202 value and zero for the rest of the items like this:

```
source_t=tensor[[101,2001,2034,1045,202,3454,3453,1234,202]
         ,[101,1999,2808,202,17658,3454,202,0,0]
         ,[101,2012,3832,4027,3454,202,3454,9987,202]]

destination_t=tensor[[101,2001,2034,1045,202,0,0,0,0]
                    ,[101,1999,2808,202,0,0,0,0,0]
                    ,[101,2012,3832,4027,3454,202,0,0,0]]
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make working and pretty efficient solution.

I have made a little bit more complex source tensor with additional rows with 202 in different places:

```
import copy
import torch

source_t = torch.tensor([[101, 2001, 2034, 1045, 202, 3454, 3453, 1234, 202],
                         [101, 1999, 2808, 202, 17658, 3454, 202, 0, 0],
                         [101, 2012, 3832, 4027, 3454, 2020, 3454, 9987, 2020],
                         [101, 2012, 3832, 4027, 3454, 202, 3454, 9987, 202],
                         [101, 2012, 3832, 4027, 3454, 2020, 3454, 9987, 202]
                         ])
```

At the start, we should find occurrences of the first 202. We can find all occurrences and then choose the first one:

```
index_202 = (source_t == 202).nonzero(as_tuple=False).numpy()
rows_for_replace = list()
columns_to_replace = list()

elements = source_t.shape[1]
current_ind = 0

while current_ind < len(index_202)-1:
    current = index_202[current_ind]
    element_ind = current[1] + 1
    rows_for_replace.extend([current[0]]*(elements-element_ind))
    while element_ind < elements:
        columns_to_replace.append(element_ind)
        element_ind += 1
    if current[0] == index_202[current_ind+1][0]:
        current_ind += 1
    current_ind += 1
```

After this operation, we have all our indexes which we should replace with zeros. 4 elements in the first row, 5 in the second, 3 in the fourth row and nothing in the third and fifth.
`rows_for_replace, columns_to_replace`

```
([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6])
```

Then we just copy our source tensor and set new values in place:

```
destination_t = copy.deepcopy(source_t)
destination_t[rows_for_replace, columns_to_replace] = 0
```

Summary:
source_t

```
tensor([[  101,  2001,  2034,  1045,   202,  3454,  3453,  1234,   202],
        [  101,  1999,  2808,   202, 17658,  3454,   202,     0,     0],
        [  101,  2012,  3832,  4027,  3454,  2020,  3454,  9987,  2020],
        [  101,  2012,  3832,  4027,  3454,   202,  3454,  9987,   202],
        [  101,  2012,  3832,  4027,  3454,  2020,  3454,  9987,   202]])
```

destination_t

```
tensor([[ 101, 2001, 2034, 1045,  202,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [ 101, 1999, 2808,  202,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [ 101, 2012, 3832, 4027, 3454, 2020, 3454, 9987, 2020],
        [ 101, 2012, 3832, 4027, 3454,  202,    0,    0,    0],
        [ 101, 2012, 3832, 4027, 3454, 2020, 3454, 9987,  202]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But is there a more efficient solution especially when the number of columns is high (384 instead of 9)? In my case, the number of columns for all rows is constant (for example is 384). How to use scatter_?

Comment: Reimplement the main function, so indexing is much efficient now.
Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution, it requires every row to have a "202", otherwise you'll have to remove the rows where this isn't the case.

```
import torch

t = torch.tensor([[101,2001,2034,1045,202,3454,3453,1234,202],
                  [101,1999,2808,202,17658,3454,202,0,0],
                  [101,2012,3832,4027,3454,202,3454,9987,202]])
out = t.clone() # make copy
```

Check where the tensor is equal to 202, convert boolean to int and the take the argmax for each row, meaning that we have the column where the first 1 appears, which corresponds to the first 202.

Then iterate over each row

```
cols = t.eq(202).int().argmax(1)
k = t.shape[1] # number of columns

for idx, c in enumerate(cols):
    if c + 1 < k:
        out[idx, c+1:] = 0 # make all values right of c equal to zero
```